# Minizinc "Exactly" question. Error during compilation

Tags: compiler-errors, minizinc

I have a quesiton on "exactly" predicate in minizinc...

```
include "exactly.mzn";


%Scalar data
int: Warehouses; 
int: Stores; 
%Vectors
array [1..Stores, 1..Warehouses] of int: SupplyCost; %delivery price
array [1..Warehouses] of int: Capacity; %warehouse capacity
array [1..Warehouses] of int: FixedCost; %cost of warehouses to be open.
array [1..Stores] of int: Goods; %request of goods from each store

%Decision Variables
array [1..Stores, 1..Warehouses] of var 0..max(Goods): GoodsMoved; 
array [1..Warehouses] of var 0..1: OpenWarehouses;
var 0..sum(SupplyCost): TransportationCost;
var 0..sum(FixedCost): OpeningCost;
var int: TotalCost; 


%Constraints


          %quantity of goods requested equal to request
constraint forall(r in 1..Stores)
           (sum (c in 1..Warehouses)
            (GoodsMoved[r,c]) = Goods[r]); 

          %total quantity of goods taken from a warehouse cannot exceed capacity
constraint forall(y in 1..Warehouses)
           (sum (x in 1..Stores) 
            (GoodsMoved[x,y]) <= Capacity[y]);


          %Exactly one 1 in OpenWarehouses: only one warehouse is open
constraint forall (c in  1..Warehouses) (exactly(1,OpenWarehouses[c],1));


            %Which warehouses are open
constraint forall (c in 1..Warehouses)
        (if (sum(r in 1..Stores) (GoodsMoved[r,c]))=0
        then OpenWarehouses[c]=0
        else OpenWarehouses[c]=1
        endif);




           %Assignment 2        
constraint TotalCost = sum (r in 1..Stores) (sum(c in 1..Warehouses) (SupplyCost[r,c]*GoodsMoved[r,c])) + sum(x in 1..Warehouses) (OpenWarehouses[x]*FixedCost[x]);






solve minimize TotalCost;


output ["\(GoodsMoved[s,w])" ++ if w=Warehouses then "\n" else " " endif | s in 1..Stores, w in 1..Warehouses];
output["\(OpenWarehouses)" ++ "\n"];
output["\(TotalCost)"];
```

This is my code... i checked at this link how it is supposed to work: https://www.minizinc.org/downloads/doc-0.11/mzn-globals.html#exactly
.

But i still get this error:

> MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `exactly(int,var int,int)'

basically what i'm trying to achieve is to have only one element initialized as 1 in the "OpenWarehouses" array

Answer (score 1):

It was a sintax error... `constraint exactly(1,OpenWarehouses,1);`
This is the correct sintax apparently.